# Dealing with different JSONArray types

Tags: java, json, tree

I have a program that reads in a simple JSON file and manipulates the data. I then store this data in trees (albeit badly). I have a problem where arguments can longs e.g {1,2}, longs and variables e.g {1,x2}, or variables with other variables e.g. {x1,x2}.

I have been able to retrieve the variables from the JSONArray. The problem arises when I have a variable and a value. I can't for the life of me figure out how to deal with such an occurrence. I apologise for the excessive use of try-catch operations. If anyone could help me solve this issue, it would be much appreciated.

```
public class program {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File();
    File outputfile = new File();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 
    FileWriter(outputfile, true)));

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        // creates object of parsed file
        Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));

        // casts object to jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

        // gets declaration-list JSONArray from the object created.
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("declaration-list");

        // Surrounding this in a try-catch would allow me to deal with the
        // different value cases unlike the frist time i wrote it
        try {

            /*
             * iterator to cycle through the array. Made the mistake last
             * time of continuously calling a method
             */

            Iterator iterator = jsonArray.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
                String variableName = (String) jo.get("declared-variable");
                MyTreeNode<String> root = new MyTreeNode<>(variableName);

                try {

                    long value = (long) jo.get("value");

                    MyTreeNode<Long> child1 = new MyTreeNode(value);

                    System.out.println(root.getData());

                    root.addChild(child1);

                    for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(node.getData());
                    }

                    test.put(variableName, value);

                    // numPrint(test, variableName, pw);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    final JSONObject jsonValue = (JSONObject) jo.get("value");

                    final String operator = (String) jsonValue.get("operator");
                    final JSONArray arguments = (JSONArray) jsonValue.get("arguments");

                    ArrayList values[] = new ArrayList[arguments.size()];


                    if (operator.equals("set")) {


                        for(int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++){

                            try{

                            //prints nested variables   

                            JSONObject jtest = (JSONObject) arguments.get(i);
                            String varval = (String) jtest.get("variable");
                            System.out.println(varval);
                            }catch(Exception g){


                            }

                        }

                        MyTreeNode<myObject> test1 = new MyTreeNode(new myObject(operator, arguments));
                        root.addChild(test1);

                        for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {

                            System.out.print(root.getData());
                            System.out.print(" = ");
                            System.out.println(node.getData());

                        }

                    }

                    if (operator.equals("pair")) {

                        MyTreeNode<myObject> test1 = new MyTreeNode(new myObject(operator, arguments));

                        root.addChild(test1);

                        for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
                            System.out.print(root.getData() + " = ");

                            System.out.println(node.getData());

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("oops");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Input file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not parsed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

}
```

}

```
class MyTreeNode<T> {
private T data = null;
private List<MyTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
private MyTreeNode parent = null;

public MyTreeNode(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void addChild(MyTreeNode child) {
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public void addChild(T data) {
    MyTreeNode<T> newChild = new MyTreeNode<>(data);
    newChild.setParent(this);
    children.add(newChild);
}

public void addChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
    for (MyTreeNode t : children) {
        t.setParent(this);
    }
    this.children.addAll(children);
}

public List<MyTreeNode> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

private void setParent(MyTreeNode parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public MyTreeNode getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

}

```
class myObject {

String operator;
JSONArray arguments;

public myObject(String operator, JSONArray arguments) {

    this.operator = operator;
    this.arguments = arguments;

}

public JSONArray get() {
    return arguments;
}

public String toString() {

    if (arguments.size() == 0) {

        return "{}";
    }

    if (operator.equals("pair")) {

        return "(" + arguments.get(0) + "," + arguments.get(1) + ")";

    } else if (operator.equals("set")) {

        String concat = "{" + arguments.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < arguments.size(); i++) {
            concat += "," + arguments.get(i);
        }

        return concat += "}";
    }

    return "wot";

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In order to process the `JSONArray`, I suggest that you create a method which checks the type of the object first and then delegates the processing to other specialised methods based on its type.

This will allow you re-use the code in case you have arrays in arrays and also to navigate through the JSON tree.

Something along these lines:

```
private static void processArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    jsonArray.forEach(o -> {
        if (o instanceof Number) {
            processNumber((Number) o);
        } else if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
            process((JSONObject) o);
        } else if (o instanceof String) {
            process((String) o);
        } else if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
            processArray((JSONArray) o); // recursive call here.
        }
    });
}
```

Other methods would look like:

```
private static void process(String o) {
    System.out.println(o); // just an example
}

public static void processNumber(Number number) {
    System.out.println(number); // just an example
}
```

And the most complex would be the one for processing objects:

```
private static void process(JSONObject o) {
    o.forEach((s, o1) -> {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (o1 instanceof Number) {
            processNumber((Number) o1);
        } else if (o1 instanceof JSONObject) {
            process((JSONObject) o1); // recursion
        } else if (o1 instanceof String) {
            process((String) o1);
        } else if (o1 instanceof JSONArray) {
            processArray((JSONArray) o1);
        }
    });
}
```

This method would also be recursive. With this type of approach you can navigate through all objects in the tree.

**Update:**

If you want to process JSON like:

```
{
  "declared-variable": "x17",
  "value": {
    "operator": "set",
    "arguments": [
      1,
      2,
      {
        "variable": "x8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

you can do so by creating a main method similar to this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
    try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("array_mixed.json")) {
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(in);
        if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            processArray((JSONArray) obj);
        }
        else if(obj instanceof Object) {
            process((JSONObject) obj);
        }
    }
}
```

This main method together with the other methods described can at least print out all the elements in the JSON.

You should be able to at least print out the following in the case of the specified JSON above:

```
declared-variable
x17
value
arguments
1
2
variable
x8
operator
set
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. For example with this JSON statement

    {
            "declared-variable" : "x17",
            "value" : {
                "operator" : "set",
                "arguments" : [
                    1,
                    2,
                    {
                        "variable" : "x8"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },

I want to be able to store the values 1,2 and variable x8 in the tree and then print it out like this: {1,2,x8}. I'm sorry if what you've suggested is suffice and I haven't understood it.

Comment: Actually it should work with a minor tweak (I did not prepare the main method to deal with objects at the root). Please check the updated answer which will allow you to deal with JSON objects at the root.